# A generalized theorem of Hall's marriage theorem

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

We all know Hall's marriage theorem as following:

> A bipartite graph $G$ with bipartition $\{ A,B \}$ contains a matching of $A$ if and only if $|N(S)|\geq |S|$ for all $S\subseteq A$.

And I am thinking about a generalized theorem of it.

> A bipartite graph $G$ with bipartition $\{ A,B \}$ contains a $k$-matching of $A$ if and only if$|N(S)|\geq k|S|$ for all $S\subseteq A$. (A $k$-matching means a subgraph $G'$ of $G$ which $A\subseteq G'$ and $d_{G'}(A_i)=k$ and for $i\neq j$, $neighbor(A_i) \cap neighbor(A_j)=\varnothing$)

Is it right? How to prove?

See a math.SE post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481389/a-generalized-theorem-of-halls-marriage-theorem

Comment: This is usually known as the polygamous version of Hall's Marriage Theorem, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is right. Just consider $k$ copies of each vertex in $A$ and apply usual Hall theorem to the new graph.